# Why we need different types of VLANS

Tags: networking, local-area-network, vlan

Why we need different types of VLANs like Port based,Protocol based ...
Give me situations where exactly those types are useful

Comment: As of today, all five of your questions are about to VLANs.  Homework questions [are not necessarily discouraged here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), but perhaps you should be asking, instead, which technical references would most benefit your studies.

Answer (score 1):

This is not different types of Vlan, this is different way to affect the vlan to packet.
Most common one is port based, it's easier way as you statically assign a Vlan to all packet coming in a particular port.
In some situation you can't do port based vlan, like in Wireless networks where user are not connected to a physical port. In this case, for Wi-Fi, most of the time vlan will be assigned base on the SSID of the Wi-Fi network.
Another commun vlan assignment method is by mac-address.